# Java property file or table in database?

Tags: java, database, user-interface

Requirement: The UI for one of the screen is user specific. Each user has the privilege of changing the color setting specific to his needs. The users for application may change.

Is it good approach to go with storing the user settings in a property file instead of having it stored in the database?

Comment: It highly depends on many things therefore there will be not a single correct answer to this question without having more informations.

Comment: use a property file, is more efficient in this case i supose, and is more easy to do, because you dont need to work with a database. When appears a need user, is faster to write the new line, that to do the consult.

Comment: @Uwe - our precise requirement is: a schedule is getting generated for a day. This corresponds to scheduling many skills for a specific day. Now there can be multiple user for this system where each user can have his own choice of color to be displayed for a particular skill. So a solution to this we thought of keeping the user specific setting in a property file instead of querying the db each time a user logs in to see the schedule. Sample property file:  User1.Skill1.ColorSkill1= RED User1.Skill2.ColorSkill2= YELLOW User2.Skill1.ColorSkill1= GREEN User2.Skill2.ColorSkill2= YELLOW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its up to your convenient and ease of usage, for this kind of similar requirement I've created a separate table for keeping those configuration.

**A Sample CRM Configuration screen :**
[image: CRM Configuration]